# How to save windows standard user settings to the registry

Tags: c#, windows, permissions

We would like to change a PC's user to a standard user, but a program I created runs this PC reading and writing to the registry. Easiest solution would probably be to just use an ini file, but I would like to know if it is possible to still write to the registry when logged in as a standard user.

For starters would this still work (creating, reading and writing to a current user registry key)? And if not, is there a workaround?

code for reading:

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey registryKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("zebra_labelprint");
int isBigLabel = int.Parse(registryKey.GetValue("biglabel", "0").ToString());
registryKey.Close();
```

writing:

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey registryKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("zebra_labelprint");
registryKey.SetValue("biglabel", ""+value);
registryKey.Close();
```

Comment: Yes, the correct solution is to save the settings to the current user's hive, though they should be in `HKCU\Software\zebra_labelprint` rather than just `HKCU\zebra_labelprint`.

Comment: This is that one time that a comment should be an answer in stead of the other way around. Thank you!